# Can't run individual nosetests from a PyQt GUI I've made - ValueError: No such test

Tags: python, pyqt, nose, nosetests

I've created a GUI for running nosetests in PyQt.

GUI code: http://pastebin.com/uVhkdDZc
My code: http://pastebin.com/3MG8PJn0

My interface reads the files in a folder of unittests and then populates a combobox with those tests and in turn, another combo box based on the tests it finds in the selected test file.

Based on [these docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/man.html) I thought I could run `nosetests /path/to/test/file.py:test_function`

However when I try to run a specific test within my unittest.py file I get a `ValueError: No such test test_123`

An example of the command that my interface generates is:
`nosetests C:\path\to\my\unittest.py:test_123`
And yet unittest.py contains `def test_123():`

So where am I going wrong? Do I need to add to my test? The setup/teardowns just currently `pass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should perhaps of been more obvious than I thought, but as always when I follow docs to set things up I overlook the basics.

Because my tests are setup within a class the class needs to be referenced when calling a single test from within that class.

So where I tried to call a test with
`nosetests C:\path\to\my\unittest.py:test_123`

I should have ran that in relation to it's class with
`nosetests C:\path\to\my\unittest.py:tests.test_123`